# What should I compare google play subscription expiry time to?

Tags: android, api, rest, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

So, I am implementing a mechanism for validating Google Play suubscriptions.

I use Android Publisher API to get subscription status (I use the method `Purchases.subscriptions: get` - https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

It returns a dictionary:

```
{  
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "startTimeMillis": long,
  "expiryTimeMillis": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean
}
```

Everything seems fine, but... what should I check `expiryTimeMillis` against? For some reason google does not return it's server time in the response. I may assume it is UTC+0, but I am not sure and even if it is the right thing to do is to check expirey time that I got from Google against their own server time, but where can I get current timestamp from the publishing API?

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is dodgy at best. I would compare it to UTC on your own server.

Comment: Hello,can you help me out.I'm stuck at the authorisation part how did you made it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as It turned out, the only thing you really can do is to compare it to UTC time on your server.

To avoid problems you should set up time sync on your server via NTP daemon.